# What is a transaction units for Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, database, azure

[image]

When you create a Azure SQL Database (Cloud version of SQL Server) free account, it informs about `10 database transaction units`.

I know clearly about transactions in SQL Server. For example, if I do a `INSERT` query, even if I don't explicitly start a transaction, it would start a transaction.

[IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

But, what is a transaction unit? Just same with a transaction? I don't think so. If so, the usage is too short. What can I do with that limited usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is a transaction unit? Just same with a transaction? I don't
> think so.

You are correct that database transaction units are unrelated to database transactions. Below is an excerpt from the [DTU-based purchasing model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/purchasing-models?view=azuresql-db#dtu-purchasing-model) page with the official definition:

> A database transaction unit (DTU) represents a blended measure of CPU,
> memory, reads, and writes.

DTUs are used in the DTU-based purchasing model to provide a relative indicator of available resources. For example, increasing from an S0 service tier (10 DTUs) to S1 (20 DTUs) will double CPU, memory, and IO resources.